# Cannot convert long int* to double* in initialization

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am working on my own C++ project and want to do below scenario:

1. Writing some values into `long int` array
2. Reading `double` from `long int` array int `double` array

So, I wrote the code as below:

```
long int lArray [100];
double dArray[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
   lArray[i] = i * i;

double *dPointer = lArray;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
   dArray[i] = *(dPointer++ + 1);
```

But, When I compile that, face `[Error] cannot convert long int* to double* in initialization` error.
How can I solve this problem?!

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: It depends on what you want to do: convert `long` to `double` numerically, or just treat `long`'s binary representation as `double`.

Comment: yes, please clarify the purpose of the line: double *dPointer = lArray;

Comment: @Anton Savin: For example when I wrote `0CDEFF3333333333` into `long int` array and load it into `double`, I means `1.10831057258179508893524397544E-246`!

Comment: @GézaTörök: dPointer points to lArray start address.

Comment: also why *(dPointer + 1);?  you never increment dPointer.

Comment: You probably just want `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) dArray[i] = static_cast<double>(lArray[i]);`

Comment: I think you want to use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Remember to compile your code with `-fno-strict-aliasing` or equivalent compiler argument if you need to do this.

Comment: @HosseinMobasher Assuming dPointer could have been set, *(dPointer++ + 1); will access out of bounds data at the end of the array.. drop the + 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to interpret `long`s as `double`s, you should use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
double *dPointer = reinterpret_cast<double*>(lArray);
```

You should also ensure that `sizeof(double) == sizeof(long)`, because for example in VS it doesn't hold (better use `unsigned long long`):

```
static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(long), "sizes are different");
```

Comment: +1 for static_assert.  Its the right thing to do when performing this kind of cast

Answer (score 4):

First up, you need to explicitly cast the pointers:

```
double *dPointer = reinterpret_cast<double*>(lArray);
```

However, the encoding of `long int` isn't compatible with the encoding of a `double`. They may both be 8 bytes wide (depending on your platform) but that's about it. The only guarantee is that a both represent zero as 8 0-bytes. Anything else isn't compatible, that's why your long is `0CDEFF3333333333` but as a double it `1.10831057258179508893524397544E-246`.

Why not just use an array of `double` in the first place? Also, since you're doing C++ take a look at the `vector` and `array` templates in the standard library.